# Format of 2013-04-09T10:00:00Z in php

Tags: php

I'm looking for the `date()` format that will give me a date like this:

```
2013-04-09T10:00:00Z
```

Is there something simpler than just using the format `'Y-m-d ...'`?

Comment: @JohnConde So is *this* Not a question?

Comment: echo (new DateTime)->format("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z");

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The date format `'c'` (ISO 8601) used with `gmdate()` (for UTC time) comes very close:

```
2013-04-09T10:00:00+00:00
```

You just need to modify it by replacing the trailing `+00:00` with `Z` (for Zulu):

```
echo substr_replace(gmdate('c'), 'Z', -6);
```

The alternative is simply this:

```
echo gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');
```

Answer (score 3):

```
date("c");
```

may be what you search? The suffix you can change yourself with explode etc.