# changing ISO date-time format in php

Tags: php, regex

I am getting ISO datetime using below code

```
$date= date("c");
echo $date;
```

which returns something like below

```
2016-01-07T20:18:46+00:00
```

But the API I use tells that its wrong format and it needs in below format:

```
2016-01-07T20:35:06+00Z
```

I need to remove `:00` at the end and add `Z`.

I am completely new to regex , can anyone help me understand the regex and tell which format is required.

Comment: Ok I understood the format , how to change the ISO format in php

Comment: @stribizhev thank you very useful , I understood the format see my edit  , also now can you tell how to change to that format in php

Comment: [Convert date format yyyy-mm-dd => dd-mm-yyyy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487921/convert-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-dd-mm-yyyy) - there others, tons of such questions.

Comment: not really yyyy mm dd is correct , I need to add remove :00 at and and Z , should i do with str replace or any other default way to do it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format of 2013-04-09T10:00:00Z in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15902464/format-of-2013-04-09t100000z-in-php)

Comment: @War10ck: That is not a dupe - there is just no way to use the hours only in *difference to UTC with or without colon between hours and minutes*. I tried myself for about an hour, checking the documentation. [Format of 2013-04-09T10:00:00Z in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15902464/format-of-2013-04-09t100000z-in-php) does not provide the answer for this question since OP needs to keep `+00`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to define the date format specifically.

If microseconds will always be 00

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s+00\Z");
```

Else, use this little big of logic

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s+"). substr((string)microtime(), 2, 2) . 'Z';
```

More info.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Aren't you hardcoding `+00`?

Comment: I did kinda assume that the value would always be 00 based on his example, but you may be right. I'm assuming that's microseconds.  I'll update my answer with a fix.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the last occurrence of `:` with [`strrpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php), and get the substring up to it with [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php), and then add `Z`:

```
$date= date("c");
echo "Current: $date\n";      // => 2016-01-07T21:58:08+00:00
$new_date =  substr($date, 0, strrpos($date, ":")) . "Z";
echo "New    : " . $new_date; // => 2016-01-07T22:10:54+00Z
```

See [demo](http://ideone.com/hzWnaU)

Comment: Didn't I suggest the working solution with `substr` earlier? I do not see the advantage of the method suggested in the other answer.